# Highlight Sinatra structure

Tags: ruby, rubygems, sinatra, bundler

I actually build a Sinatra app and I'd like to clear some point in Ruby/bundler etc...

What's about requiring the `rubygems` on the `config.ru`? Many folks do this but why?

Same question for requiring `bundler/setup` into the `app.rb`? Some guys said it's requiring every gems we have into the `Gemfile` but is it true? (in this case, we'd don't have to require `sinatra`, `active_record`...).

Last things I don't really understand is the requiring. The first entry point is `config.ru`. So if we require `rubygems` and then `./app.rb`, we'd don't have to require `rubygems` into `./app.rb`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What's about requiring the rubygems on the config.ru? Many folks do this but why?

It doesn't matter as, since Ruby v1.9, it's been required by default anyway. I checked a project I'm working on and I've got it right there at the top, so it's just there for no good reason! Maybe I'll get rid of it now…

See http://www.rubyinside.com/why-using-require-rubygems-is-wrong-1478.html for more on this.

> Same question for requiring bundler/setup into the app.rb? Some guys said it's requiring every gems we have into the Gemfile but is it true? (in this case, we'd don't have to require sinatra, active_record...).

Yes, [Bundler will handle `require` for you if you tell it to](http://anti-pattern.com/bundler-setup-vs-bundler-require), but I actually use [this style](http://bundler.io/v1.6/bundler_setup.html):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'
Bundler.setup(:default, :ci)
require 'nokogiri'
```

as I like to handle my own `require`s, it makes testing (generally) quicker and more particular, IMO.

Note also, from the linked docs:

> For another kind of application (such as a Sinatra application), you will need to set up bundler before trying to require any gems.

Lastly,

> The first entry point is config.ru. So if we require rubygems and then ./app.rb, we'd don't have to require rubygems into ./app.rb, right?

Yes, [`require` will only load a library once](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Kernel.html#method-i-require).

> Loads the given name, returning true if successful and false if the feature is already loaded.